# Need assistance on my Music Player for android

Tags: java, android

So I previously asked a similar question and only got a few comments saying search up on google, and I did. I found nothing. Well nothing that worked for me.

What I want to do is, expand my music player. for example... I would like to create an inbuilt library that displays all the music files from my device. And when I select the song it'll play. And at the bottom it'll display the following buttons - shuffle, previous song, play/pause, next song, repeat function"

Here's my MainActivity -

```
package com.ascendapps.holoplayer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
        play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.dummy);
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, path);
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });

        Button stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);
        stop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                    mediaPlayer.release();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    // --
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if(mediaPlayer!=null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.release();mediaPlayer = null;
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

And here is my activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/play"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2.5dip"
        android:background="#ff4c4c"
        android:text="@string/Play" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2.5dip"
        android:background="#4cb4ff"
        android:text="@string/Stop" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Any help on how to do the above will be kindly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make my android app display music from my device?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22853188/how-to-make-my-android-app-display-music-from-my-device)

Comment: `displays all the music files from my device` means from particular folder or from entire device.

Comment: @InnocentKiller - The entire device. Like I want to build a basic Music player which has standard functions that displays my music fro my device and when selecting it, it play.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the accepted answer is just a tutorial link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow this http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-building-audio-player-tutorial/ I hope you will get everything you want.